# Multiple SVN working copies on different computers

Tags: svn, version-control

I will use an SVN working copy in the office and at home. Is it safe to use the same SVN user for them? Can I simply commit something in the office, then make an update at home, continue the work and make new modifications in the repo etc?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards: Balazs

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Comment: If you don't, changes will be recorded as coming from different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!
SVN checks out two different Workingcopies.

SVN does not keep track of checked out workingcopies or the user.

If you commit something it sends the request to the server and the server checks:

- are your credentials vaild (write accesss)?
- are all files you want to modify on HEAD (there is no newer version on the server than the versions on your working copy)

If both checks went fine it will transfer the content(as difference to the previous version) and creates a new revision.
This is fully independent from the number of working copies. A valid analogy would be to use login to StackOverflow from your home and office computer. This both works as well :) .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this StackOverflow analogy is really great.